# Javascript run object and all this methods

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I've created the following jQuery OOP code

```
(function ($) {

    example = {
      method1 : function()  {},
      method2   : function()  {}        
    };


})(jQuery);
```

I don't want to use `init()` and call some methods on document ready. Is there any way to execute/run the object in literal notation??  I used `var example = new Object();` but I'm getting error, I just need all the methods associated to the objects to be running on ready.

Comment: Do you plan to use the example object later in your code?

Comment: hi , not really ..  it's  just  the flow

Answer (score 2):

This will do it :)

```
(function ($) {

    // define some methods
    var example = {
      method1: function() { console.log(1); },
      method2: function() { console.log(2); }        
    };

    // run all methods in example
    for (var m in example) {
      if (example.hasOwnProperty(m) && typeof example[m] === "function") {
        example[m]();
      }
    }

    // => 1
    // => 2

})(jQuery);
```

---

If you want to use `new` such as

```
var example = new Example();
// => "A"
// => "B"
```

You could do something like this

```
(function($) {

  var Example = function() {
    this.initializeA();
    this.initializeB();  
  };

  Example.prototype.initializeA = function() {
    console.log('A');
  }

  Example.prototype.initializeB = function() {
    console.log('B');
  };

  // init
  new Example();
  // => "A"
  // => "B"

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @AdamRackis, sorry about that. I was editing the answer to add more details and it overwrote your change. Your change looks good though, thanks.

Comment: hi , thanks it works  i am aware of this logic too , but  i was thinking it's  there any other simpler way to initialize the methods of object without any overload. example if object contains  100+ odd methods i am afraid of the time of execution. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
(function ($) {

    example = (function() {alert("some code")})();
    //or
    (function() {alert("some other code")})();
    //or
    alert("even more code");

})(jQuery);
```